# Jhipster 2.27 : can't create an entity

Tags: jhipster

I have forked Jhipster 2.27 and tried to add an entity with 
yo jhipster:entity car

I got this error :

```
events.js:154  
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event  
      ^  


TypeError: Cannot read property 'endsWith' of undefined  
    at Generator.getAngularAppName   (/home/myUbuntu/dev/workspace/generator-jhipster-master/generators/generator-base.js:1223:67)  
    at module.exports.EntityGenerator.extend.initializing.getConfig (/home/myUbuntu/dev/workspace/generator-jhipster-master/generators/entity/index.js:116:40)  
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/myUbuntu/dev/workspace/generator-jhipster-master/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:436:25)  
    at /home/myUbuntu/dev/workspace/generator-jhipster-master/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/run-async/index.js:24:25  
    at /home/myUbuntu/dev/workspace/generator-jhipster-master/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:448:8  
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

.yo-rc.json file :

```
  GNU nano 2.4.2                                                      Fichier : .yo-rc.json                                                                                                                 

{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "jhipsterVersion": "2.27.0",
    "baseName": "jhipster",
    "packageName": "com.myApp.testapp",
    "packageFolder": "com/myApp/testapp",
    "authenticationType": "session",
    "hibernateCache": "ehcache",
    "clusteredHttpSession": "no",
    "websocket": "no",
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": "no",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "rememberMeKey": "c959bf1efd5c74e68c9700e2ad012ff595ed52ec",
    "useSass": false,
    "languages": [
      "fr",
      "ca"
    ]
  },
  "testapp": {
    "jhipsterVersion": "2.27.0",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "baseName": "jhipster",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling"
    ],
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "fr",
    "languages": [
      "fr",
      "ca"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any idea of what's going wrong here?

Thank you.

**[UPDATE]** 
This is what I did :

```
Welcome to the JHipster Generator v2.27.0
Application files will be generated in folder: /home/myUbuntu/dev/workspace/generator-jhipster-master
? (1/15) Which *type* of application would you like to create? Monolithic application (recommended for simple projects)
? (2/15) What is the base name of your application? jhipster
? (3/15) What is your default Java package name? com.myapp.testapp
? (4/15) Which *type* of authentication would you like to use? HTTP Session Authentication (stateful, default Spring Security mechanism)
? (5/15) Which *type* of database would you like to use? SQL (H2, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle)
? (6/15) Which *production* database would you like to use? MySQL
? (7/15) Which *development* database would you like to use? MySQL
? (8/15) Do you want to use Hibernate 2nd level cache? Yes, with ehcache (local cache, for a single node)
? (9/15) Do you want to use a search engine in your application? No
? (10/15) Do you want to use clustered HTTP sessions? No
? (11/15) Do you want to use WebSockets? No
? (12/15) Would you like to use Maven or Gradle for building the backend? Maven
? (13/15) Would you like to use the LibSass stylesheet preprocessor for your CSS? No
? (14/15) Would you like to enable internationalization support? Yes
? Please choose the native language of the application? French
? Please choose additional languages to install Catalan
? (15/15) Which testing frameworks would you like to use? Gatling

Installing languages: fr, ca
   create bower.json
 conflict package.json
? Overwrite package.json? overwrite
    force package.json
 conflict README.md
? Overwrite README.md? overwrite
    force README.md
 conflict .gitignore
? Overwrite .gitignore? overwrite
    force .gitignore
 conflict .gitattributes
? Overwrite .gitattributes? overwrite
    force .gitattributes
 conflict .editorconfig
? Overwrite .editorconfig? overwrite
    force .editorconfig
 conflict .travis.yml
? Overwrite .travis.yml? overwrite
```

then :

> yo jhipster:entity car

.yo-rc.json file : 
  GNU nano 2.4.2                                                      Fichier : .yo-rc.json

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "jhipsterVersion": "2.27.0",
    "baseName": "jhipster",
    "packageName": "com.myapp.testapp",
    "packageFolder": "com/myapp/testapp",
    "authenticationType": "session",
    "hibernateCache": "ehcache",
    "clusteredHttpSession": "no",
    "websocket": "no",
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": "no",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "rememberMeKey": "6b7f2e0be835e1ec6541cf6607c28d97edca19cc",
    "useSass": false,
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling"
    ],
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "fr",
    "languages": [
      "fr",
      "ca"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Update2**

> npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-16-generic npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node"
>   "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" npm ERR! node v5.6.0 npm ERR! npm 
>   v3.6.0
>
> npm ERR! No compatible version found: generator-jhipster@0.0.0 npm
>   ERR! Valid install targets: npm ERR! 2.27.2, 2.27.1, 2.27.0, 2.26.2,
>   2.26.1, 2.26.0, 2.25.0, 2.24.0, 2.23.1, 2.23.0, 2.22.0, 2.21.1, 2.21.0, 2.20.0, 2.19.0, 2.18.0, 2.17.0, 2.16.1, 2.16.0, 2.15.2, 2.15.1, 2.15.0, 2.14.2, 2.14.1, 2.14.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.0, 2.12.0, 2.11.1, 2.11.0, 2.10.1, 2.10.0, 2.9.2, 2.9.1, 2.9.0, 2.8.0, 2.7.0, 2.6.0, 2.5.2, 2.5.1, 2.5.0, 2.4.0, 2.3.0, 2.2.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.0, 1.10.2, 1.10.1, 1.10.0, 1.9.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.0, 1.6.0, 1.5.0, 1.4.0, 1.3.0, 1.2.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.0, 0.18.1, 0.18.0, 0.17.2, 0.17.1, 0.17.0, 0.16.0, 0.15.0, 0.14.0, 0.13.0, 0.12.0, 0.11.0, 0.10.1, 0.10.0, 0.9.3, 0.9.2, 0.9.1, 0.9.0, 0.8.4, 0.8.3, 0.8.2, 0.8.1, 0.8.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.0, 0.6.2, 0.6.1, 0.6.0, 0.5.2, 0.5.1, 0.5.0, 0.4.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.0, 0.1.0, 0.0.29, 0.0.28, 0.0.27, 0.0.26, 0.0.23, 0.0.22, 0.0.21, 0.0.20, 0.0.19, 0.0.18, 0.0.17, 0.0.16, 0.0.15, 0.0.14, 0.0.13, 0.0.12, 0.0.11, 0.0.10, 0.0.9, 0.0.8, 0.0.7, 0.0.6, 0.0.5, 0.0.4, 0.0.3, 0.0.2, 0.0.1 npm ERR!  npm ERR!  npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this
>   error at: npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /home/myUbuntu/dev/workspace/rhapp/npm-debug.log
>   module.js:341
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-autoprefixer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You haven't forked JHipster 2.27, you have forked JHipster 3.0 
   from master (2.27 is on v2.x_maintenance branch) otherwise you would have
   not been proposed to generate a monolith app.
2. It seems you have modified manually your `.yo-rc.json` file as JHipster would have rejected `com.myApp.testapp` with this error: "The package name you have provided is not a valid Java package name."
3. Your `.yo-rc.json` file is not valid, there should not be this `"testapp"` section, this is why it fails.

Here is what your `.yo-rc.json` file should be:

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "jhipsterVersion": "2.27.0",
    "baseName": "jhipster",
    "packageName": "com.myapp.testapp",
    "packageFolder": "com/myapp/testapp",
    "authenticationType": "session",
    "hibernateCache": "ehcache",
    "clusteredHttpSession": "no",
    "websocket": "no",
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": "no",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "rememberMeKey": "33cd878a5fc34f050fec62a1c0c3f4dafb64458e",
    "useSass": false,
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling"
    ],
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "fr",
    "languages": [
      "fr",
      "ca"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Update 1**

From your trace it seems that you tried to generate an app in the generator's folder, this cannot work.

> Application files will be generated in folder:
>   /home/myUbuntu/dev/workspace/generator-jhipster-master

You got to run `yo jhipster` in a new empty folder.

**Update 2**

Your last error looks like you have changed the version of the generator in its package.json. Npm then looks up this version on nmpjs.org and cannot find it.

**Update 3**

Read our docs about how to use your forked generator: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#setup

Comment: ok, I did it again from scratch (npm link, yo jhipster), you can see my updated post for details (how I filled the project creation form).

Comment: Edited to explain what you possibly did wrong from your trace.

Comment: When I run yo jhipster in a new empty folder I am getting [see update 2 in main post] I think there is something I don't understand.

Comment: I don't know how to use the generator I have forked. How to make my new project point at this generator?

Comment: This is documented here: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#setup

Comment: Basically this is done by npm link in the folder of the forked generator, then you can use the generator in another folder as usual.

Comment: what I did : i have forked generator-jhipster-master, then in this folder I have run a npm link. Then I created a new folder and ran yo jhipster and I am getting a "Welcome to the JHipster Generator v0.0.0"

Comment: finally got it working : 1-forked the project  2-cloned the project  3-ran a npm link in this folder  4- created new project folder  5- in this folder ran npm link generator jhipster 6- ran yo jhipster.  Thanks for your patience.